# Ionic 4 (Angular 7) - sharing components issue

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to do an extremely usual thing for such a framework like Angular. The goal is to use the same (**HeaderComponent**) component more than once through a shared module.

My shared.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../header/header.component';
import { IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule, 
        IonicModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

In app.module.ts I added this:

```
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, SharedModule],
```

And in home.page.html I tried to render it this way:

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

It actually worked since browser showed me errors like

> 'ion-col' is not a known element

and so on for all the ionic components from the **HeaderComponent**.

I've found a solution for the issue over the Internet that suggest adding `IonicModule.forRoot(HeaderComponent)` to the **imports** array of the **shared.module.ts**, but this approach causes the following error:

> 'app-header' is not a known element

As if it is no longer available.

Comment: pulling my hair out with this Ionic 4. How does one use shared components in Ionic 4....!!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you additionally have to add the ionic module to your shared module like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../header/header.component';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

if you are using ionic 4 you have to edit the import of IonicModule to this:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
```

Comment: IonicModule is added at root level, so no need

Comment: You're wrong. If you generate a shared component module with ionic, the module imports ionic module by default. If it's true what you are saying, why would you import commonmodule even though you import browser module in root?

Comment: yeah makes sense :)

Comment: eventually figured it out

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I was trying to include a custom component in a component that is opened with a modal. I needed to add my component to the parent page's module.

Answer (score 0):

I had lot issues with trying to create a 3rd, i.e. shared module, so I found this to be very helpful:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-create-shared-component-up-to-date-example-please/176887

I didn't follow the part about getting rid stuff but I did add a module to my component (in the same folder). Then in the other pages I was able to import this module on top then in the imports array and that worked.

Eventually I had to import other things like what Gary said above but that is just common sense.

Most tutorials I found online have you to create yet another component then use the module that comes with that. I was super confused following that line of thinking. I think it basically boils down to, you can share modules, but not components. Don't quote me but that is how I understand it now.

header.component.html

```
     <ion-header>
...

    </ion-header>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { feedService } from "../services/feed.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ...  
    ],
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    exports: [HeaderComponent],
  })
  export class HeaderModule{
  }
```

finally to use it else where, in that page's module.ts

```
import ... //other modules

import { HeaderModule  } from "../header/header.module";  //your relative path

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //other modules
    HeaderModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [],
})
export class MyPageModule {}
```

then on the that page's html file, I can use the selector declared in header.component.ts above.

`<app-header ...></app-header>`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.