# Can't import component into a page - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working with Ionic 4 and Angular 7.

I just want to build a component to reuse later in the app but I get the classic error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'home-cmp'
>   is not a known element:
>   1. If 'home-cmp' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'home-cmp' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I did a Shared module like [here](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/how-manage-shared-components-in-an-ionic-4-app/) but still can't make it work.

[I did the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993169/7857994)

the shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports : [ HomeComponent]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

module where i use it

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { PagesModule } from 'src/app/components/pages/pages.module';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Here is the file tree:

[image: file tree]

**EDIT**

I use tabs that use their own routing module

**EDIT 2**

[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020439/ionic-4-angular-7-sharing-components-issue) but no answer

Comment: Are you using the right selector from your component? Can you check that the selector from your HomeComponent is 'home-cmp' and not something else like 'app-home-cmp'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<home-cmp>` in an html file of another page, then in the module.ts of that page add the following inside `@NgModule`:

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

From the docs:

> Defines a schema that allows an NgModule to contain the following:
>
> Non-Angular elements named with dash case (-).
>
> Element properties named with dash case (-). Dash case is the naming convention for custom elements.

Comment: It doesn't work, `<home-cmp>`is an Angular element,

Comment: Add the following `schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]` you need to add it in the module.ts of the html where you use `<home-cmp>` I think you might be adding it in a wrong place

Comment: Did you add you component in the declaration array??